# How to handle RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'new_account' was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, python-asyncio, redis-server

Whenever I start *web.py* and go to `localhost:8080/register` I get this error.
It's part of a Flash game.

```py
web.py:75: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'new_account' was never awaited
  uid, password = utils.bot_common.new_account(app["redis"])
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line418, in start
    resp = await task
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 458,in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/web_middlewares.py", lne 119, in impl
    return await handler(request)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp_session/__init__.py", ine 154, in factory
    response = await handler(request)
  File "web.py", line 75, in register
    uid, password = utils.bot_common.new_account(app["redis"])
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable coroutine object
```

above error points to *web.py* Line 75:

```py
@routes.get("/register")
async def register(request):
    if not registation:
        return web.Response(text="Регистрация отключена")
    uid, password =  utils.bot_common.new_account(app["redis"])
    return web.Response(text=f"Аккаунт создан, ваш логин - {uid}, "
                             f"пароль - {password}")
```

Some more information from *bot_commony.py* register bot:

```py
import string
import random
def random_string(string_length=20):
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(string_length))

async def new_account(redis):
    await redis.incr("uids")
    uid = await redis.get("uids")
    pipe = redis.pipeline()
    pipe.set(f"uid:{uid}:lvt", 0)
    pipe.sadd(f"rooms:{uid}", "livingroom")
    pipe.rpush(f"rooms:{uid}:livingroom", "#livingRoom", 1)
    for i in range(1, 6):
        pipe.sadd(f"rooms:{uid}", f"room{i}")
        pipe.rpush(f"rooms:{uid}:room{i}", f"Комната {i}", 2)
    await pipe.execute()
    return uid
```

Comment: How ı fix  this error?

Comment: Without showing us any of your code it's really hard to tell, but you probably need to stick an `await` in there: `uid, password = await untold.bot_common.new_account(app["redis"])`

Comment: I added bot_common.py source can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

`new_account` returns a coroutine, hence

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable coroutine object
```

Coroutines need to be awaited (or wrapped in a task). To fix this specific `TypeError`, you need to update your code to

```
uid, password = await untold.bot_common.new_account(app["redis"])
```

Once you've made this change, I suspect you'll get a new `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

This is because `new_account` returns a single value: `uid`. Based on `await redis.incr("uids")`, it looks like you have an integer, not a two-character string or a container with two values in it. You'll either need to change the line in `register` to

```
uid = await untold.bot_common.new_account(app["redis"])
```

or you'll need to change `new_account` to return multiple values

```
return uid, "some password"
```